# ios UI Elements in Custom UIView not responding

Tags: uiview, uiviewcontroller, ios8

I'm using a custom UIView in myViewController. I have a SampleView which is my custom view. I have my class as..

SampleView.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *mainView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *sampleButton;
```

and in the SampleView.m

I have added a basic init

```
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        [self commonInit];
    }
    return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self commonInit];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)commonInit
{
    UIView *view = nil;
    NSArray *objects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SampleView"
                                                     owner:self
                                                   options:nil];
    for (id object in objects) {
        if ([object isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]) {
            view = object;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (view != nil) {
        _mainView = view;
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        [self addSubview:view];
        [self setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
    }
}
```

Now in my ViewController I want to change the property of the title on the sampleButton...

```
SampleView *sampleView = [[SampleView alloc]init];

sampleView.sampleButton.titleLabel.text = @"Hello";

[self.view addSubview:sampleView];
```

There is no change in the SubView's button text. Please do help me about the same.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
- (void)commonInit
{
   //UIView *view = nil;
   UIView *view=[[UIView all]init];
   ........
}
```